# Показать/скрыть группу блоков при клике на один из них

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько групп блоков, выстроенных рядами. Например, два ряда по три блока.
Под каждым блоком есть некий текстовый контент, который надо прятать/показывать при клике на блок.
Необходимо универсальное решение, которое при клике на любой блок отображает текстовый контент всех блоков в этом ряду и при этом скрывает все остальные (если открыты).
По умолчанию весь текстовый контент скрыт.
Проблема в том, что количество рядов не определено.

HTML-код ряда:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="c3 toogle">
        <p class="toogle-text">Некий текст</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c3 toogle">
        <p class="toogle-text">Некий текст</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c3 toogle">
        <p class="toogle-text">Некий текст</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Я думал добавлять индексы к каждому ряду, но это индусский вариант, а правильно я пока не умею.

```
$('.toogle').click(function() { 
    $('.toogle-text').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: $('.toogle') .click(function() {
$('.toogle-text') .slideToggle();});

Comment: я сделал оч просто, думал добавлять индексы к каждому ряду, но это индусский вариант, а прально я пока неумею

Comment: Нечего сказать помог :))

Comment: А вы хотите чтобы кто-то угадывал структуру вашего HTML-кода? Вопрос должен быть оформлен качественно. Если вы считаете, что я тут придираюсь и требую какую-то ненужную информацию, то почему тогда до сих пор не было ответа, а вопрос был почти закрыт (3/5 голосов) по причине "Необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса"? Подумайте над этим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант без javascript

```css
.toogle:not(:focus)>.hideable {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="c3 toogle" tabindex=1>статическая часть
<p class="hideable">Скрываемый текст</p>
</div>
<div class="c3 toogle" tabindex=1>статическая часть
<p class="hideable">Скрываемый текст</p>
</div>
<div class="c3 toogle" tabindex=1>статическая часть
<p class="hideable">Скрываемый текст</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Вариант с jquery, если фокус не нужен. Хотя с фокусом может быть удобнее пользователю переключать видимость Табом.

```js
$('.toogle').click(function(){
    $('.toogle').addClass('closed');
    $(this).removeClass('closed');
});
```

```css
.closed .hideable {
  display:none;
}
div.float {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="c3 toogle closed">
  <div class=float> _статическая часть_
    <p class="hideable"> Скрываемый текст </p>
  </div>
  <div class=float> _статическая часть_
    <p class="hideable"> Скрываемый текст </p>
  </div>
  <div> _статическая часть_
<p class="hideable"> Скрываемый текст </p></div>
</div>
<div class="c3 toogle closed">статическая часть
<p class="hideable">Скрываемый текст</p>
</div>
<div class="c3 toogle closed">статическая часть
<p class="hideable">Скрываемый текст</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение спасибо, дальше буду сам думать у меня три таких блока выстроено в линию под ними еще три осталось сделать чтобы при нажатии на любой блок из линии  все три открывались и так далее

Comment: внутрь "статической части" можете вбить сколько хотите блоков

Comment: Располагаются они как у lexxl, а текст выезжать должен как у вас только на всех трех в одном ряду вот в чем идея

Comment: при этом не плохо было бы при повторном клике прятать его

Comment: @ДмитрийЯковлев  изменил второй пример

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
  $('.toogle').click(function(){
    $('.toogle .toogle-text').css('opacity', '0');
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.toogle .toogle-text').css('opacity', '1');
  })
})
```

```css
.toogle {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: silver;
}
.toogle-text {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="c3 toogle">
    <p class="toogle-text">Некий текст</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c3 toogle">
    <p class="toogle-text">Некий текст</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c3 toogle">
    <p class="toogle-text">Некий текст</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="c3 toogle">
    <p class="toogle-text">Некий текст</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c3 toogle">
    <p class="toogle-text">Некий текст</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c3 toogle">
    <p class="toogle-text">Некий текст</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="c3 toogle">
    <p class="toogle-text">Некий текст</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c3 toogle">
    <p class="toogle-text">Некий текст</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c3 toogle">
    <p class="toogle-text">Некий текст</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем то что надо, текст выползает из под блока в моем случае

Comment: ну, во-первых, в вопросе этого указано не было - как сформулировано, так и отвечено. во-вторых, вопрос по функционалу отображения текста во всём, а не про анимацию появления его. используйте css и располагайте ваш текст как угодно. на javascript это никак не влияет